DAC and DMA Not Outputting on PA4 on STM32L432KC
(my code is below)
I am trying to output an analog wave out of PA4 on the STM32L4 MCU, using DMA and a DAC. Ultimately, I will pass in audio data into the MCU through I2S and use DMA and the DAC to output it. I am currently working on outputting a signal using DMA and DAC from an array and reading it on the oscilloscope. To do so, I enable the GPIO pins, enable and configure the peripherals, and set it to pass through an array of 8-bit unsigned integers that should create a sine wave when passed through the DAC. I configured DMA to write the array values directly into the DHR8R1 register and use timer 7 to trigger these transfers. I hope to see a sine wave on my oscilloscope with higher amplitudes.
I also looked at the datasheet and saw the DAC has a Vref and such. I have attached a jumper between the REF pin and 3.3V pin. Besides that, I just have the oscilloscope reading PA4 and grounded. I couldn't find how to attach the VDDA or other signals to the DAC.
Things I have tried:

From the debugging terminal, I see that I am writing to DACC1DHR and that is being passed to the DACC1DOR Register (although if I write 11111110 to the DACC1DHR, it is written as 111111100000 to the DOR1 register.

I am hooking up the oscilloscope directly to PA4, and opted to use a buffer on the DAC as it seems that it can help output higher voltages. However, I am not seeing a clear signal on the oscilloscope, only low voltage noise. I am not sure if this could be from my sampling rate, or what. I looked in the datasheet, and it doesnt look like I have to set PA4 to a special function.

I noticed that when I manually write and wait into the DHR8R1 register I do see some flucutations on the pin (albeit maybe I am delusional) , which makes me think that my clock may be running too fast -- any advice on my clock & timer configuration would be great.


Thank you!
My Code:
#include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdint.h>
 #include <stm32l432xx.h>
 #include "stm32l432xx.h"
 #include "lib/stm32L432KC.h"
 #include "lib/STM32L432KC.h"
 //#include "lib/STM32L432KC_ADC.h"
 #include "lib/STM32L432KC_FLASH.h"
 #include "lib/STM32L432KC_GPIO.h"
 #include "lib/STM32L432KC_RCC.h"
 //#include "lib/STM32L432KC_USART.h"
 //#include "lib/STM32L432KC_TIM.h"
 //#include "lib/STM32L432KC_I2S.h"
 //#include "lib/STM32L432KC_DAC.h"
 //#include "main.h"

static const uint8_t SINEWAVE[] = {
126, 136, 146, 156, 166, 175, 185, 194, 202, 210,
217, 224, 230, 235, 240, 244, 247, 249, 251, 251,
251, 250, 248, 246, 242, 238, 233, 227, 221, 214,
206, 198, 189, 180, 171, 161, 151, 141, 131, 121,
111, 101, 91, 81, 72, 63, 54, 46, 38, 31,
25, 19, 14, 10, 6, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1,
3, 5, 8, 12, 17, 22, 28, 35, 42, 50,
58, 67, 77, 86, 96, 106, 116}; // 77 samples


int main(void) {

// 1. ENABLE PINS
   RCC->AHB2ENR |= (RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOAEN | RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOBEN | RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOCEN); // Enable GPIOA


// 2. ENABLE PERIPHERALS: DMA1, DAC1, TIM7
   RCC->AHB1ENR |= (RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN);   // Enable DMA 1
   RCC->APB1ENR1 |= RCC_APB1ENR1_DAC1EN; // Enable DAC1
   RCC->APB1ENR1 |= (RCC_APB1ENR1_TIM7EN); // Enable TIM7

// 3. INITIALIZE DMA 
  // set up buffer
   DMA1_Channel3->CCR &= ~(0xffffffff); // reset values
   DMA1_Channel3->CPAR = (uint32_t) &(DAC1->DHR8R1); //Place DMA into DAC Outplacement 
   DMA1_Channel3->CMAR = (uint32_t) &SINEWAVE; // set source address to character array buffer in memory.
   DMA1_Channel3->CNDTR = sizeof(SINEWAVE); // Set DMA data transfer length (# of samples).

   DMA1_Channel3->CCR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CCR_PL, 0b10);  // set priority lvl to very high B)
   DMA1_Channel3->CCR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CCR_DIR, 0b1); // read from memory, 0b1
  // DMA1_Channel3->CCR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CCR_MEM2MEM, 0b0);

   DMA1_Channel3->CCR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CCR_CIRC, 0b1); // enable circular mode
   DMA1_Channel3->CCR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CCR_MINC, 0b1); // memory increment mode enabled
   //DMA1_Channel3->CCR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CCR_PINC, 0b1); 
   DMA1_Channel3->CCR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CCR_MSIZE, 0b00); //Memory size set to 8 bits, data size of DMA transfer in memory 
   DMA1_Channel3->CCR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CCR_PSIZE, 0b00); // peripheral size = 8 bits, Defines the data size of each DMA transfer to the identified peripheral. Set to 8, 0b00

   DMA1_CSELR->CSELR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CSELR_C3S, 0b0110); // set dma channel 3 to DAC1_channel1
   DMA1_Channel3->CCR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CCR_EN, 0b1); 
   

// 4. INITIALIZE TIMER 7
         FLASH->ACR &= ~(7 << 0);
     FLASH->ACR |= (4 << 0);       // Latency => Four wait states

     RCC->CR &= ~(1 << 24);        // Main PLL Disable
     while(RCC->CR & (1 << 24));

     RCC->PLLCFGR &= ~(3 << 0);
     RCC->PLLCFGR |= (1 << 0);     // MSI clock selected as PLL

     RCC->PLLCFGR &= ~(1 << 12);   // PLLN = 0 (just resetting)

     RCC->PLLCFGR &= ~(7 << 4);    // PLLM = 1
     RCC->PLLCFGR |= (40 << 8);    // PLLN = 40
     RCC->PLLCFGR &= ~(3 << 25);   // PLLR = 2
     RCC->PLLCFGR |= (1 << 24);    // Enable PLLR

     RCC->CR |= (1 << 24);           // Main PLL Enable
     while(!(RCC->CR & (1 << 25)));  // Wait until PLL is ready

     RCC->CFGR &= ~(3 << 0);
     RCC->CFGR |= (3 << 0);          // PLL selected as system clock

     while(!( RCC->CFGR & (3 << 2)));   // Wait until PLL used as system clock

     RCC->CFGR &= ~(1 << 7);  // AHB prescaler = 1
     RCC->CFGR &= ~(1 << 10); // APB low-speed prescaler (APB1) = 1
     RCC->CFGR &= ~(1 << 13); // APB high-speed prescaler (APB2) = 1

     SystemCoreClockUpdate();  // Update the System Clock
    
    
    // set up timer 7
    
        RCC->APB1ENR1 |= (1 << 5);  // Enable Timer 7

    TIM7->PSC = 99;  // Prescaler = 99

    TIM7->ARR = 35;  // Period =  35

    TIM7->CR2 |= (2 << 4); // Update Event

    TIM7->CR1 |= (1 << 0);  // Counter enable



// 5. INITIALIZE DAC - initDAC();
   DAC1->CR |= _VAL2FLD(DAC_CR_TEN1, 0b1); // DAC channel1 trigger enable
   DAC1->CR |= _VAL2FLD(DAC_CR_TSEL1, 0b010); // : DAC channel1 trigger selection to TIM7 (pg. 492)
   
   DAC1->MCR |= _VAL2FLD(DAC_MCR_MODE1, 0b000); // 0b000 is: DAC Channel 2 is connected to external pin with Buffer enabled
   DAC->CR |= _VAL2FLD(DAC_CR_DMAEN1, 0b1); // Enable DMA

   // traingle wave
    //DAC1->CR |= _VAL2FLD(DAC_CR_WAVE1, 0b10);
    //DAC1->CR |= _VAL2FLD(DAC_CR_MAMP1, 0b1010);
     
    DAC1->CR |= _VAL2FLD(DAC_CR_EN1, 0b1); // DAC channel powered on by setting its corresponding ENx bit in the DAC_CR register. (p. 489)


   while(1) {
     
   }
 }


Break the problem down.  Make a project without the timer or DMA and just check that you can write a single value to the DAC and see the appropriate voltage on the pin.  If you can't, your problem is with electronics or the DAC, if you can, your problem is with the timer or DMA.  Either way you have half as much code to search through.  Next break the problem down again.

BTW, the internal DAC is probably not really suitable for audio.
